# How to filter date from json by today date in dart/flutter riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to filter date from my json file based on today , tomorrow date.
Code I'm using are given below:
Fetch json data: List river = ref.watch(getDataFuture);
And show it: river[index].endDate.toString()

Comment: give your sample JSON and tell what is expected output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a json field of date (which is a number) you can just filter based on the number of today, tomorrow, etc.

E.g.:

```
final DateTime dateTime = new DateTime.now();
final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await colRef
    .doc(docId)
    .collection('subCol')
  .where('startDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: dateTimePlusMaximumEventInterval)
  .where('startDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: dateTimeMinusMaximumEvntInterval)
```